# Why Comparable natural ordering needs to be consistent with equals method?

Tags: java, generics, collections

Back after a vacation :) with the questions. I am reading Comparable interface documentation from
[ComparableDocumentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). I do understand, that we use comparable as it will provide us with sorting and natural ordering. In the documentation, it is written as.

> It is strongly recommended (though not required) that natural
>   orderings be consistent with equals. This is so because sorted sets
>   (and sorted maps) without explicit comparators behave "strangely" when
>   they are used with elements (or keys) whose natural ordering is
>   inconsistent with equals. In particular, such a sorted set (or sorted
>   map) violates the general contract for set (or map), which is defined
>   in terms of the equals method.

How does Comparable is related to equals. Comparable has compareTo method and why it needs to be consistent with the equals method? I am unable to understand this concept.

Also quoting from the sources, can someone elaborate on this point as well

> For example, if one adds two keys a and b such that (!a.equals(b) &&
>   a.compareTo(b) == 0) to a sorted set that does not use an explicit
>   comparator, the second add operation returns false (and the size of
>   the sorted set does not increase) because a and b are equivalent from
>   the sorted set's perspective.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The semantics of `compareTo` returning 0 is that the two objects are, well, *equal*. Having another definition of the same relation in the other method can obviously result in many kinds of trouble, as documented in your quote as well: the typical algorithms in `SortedSet` implementations rely on `compareTo`, but the general contract of the `Set` interface specifies that it must not contain two objects which are `equals`. The inconsistency of reports from `compareTo` and `equals` will result in just such a situation.

Comment: thanks a ton. I understand the concept now. It means that Set interface promotes equality comparison using equals method?

Comment: Yes, because the quintessential `Set` implementation doesn't care about any ordering of its elements: it just cares that they are all distinct. The primary role of `equals` is, arguably, to make `Set`s work.

Comment: Thanks a ton marko. I understand the concept now. Thankyou very much.

Comment: @benz : since it was Marko's answer that helped you, you should accept it :).

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato, i am doing it, i was just adding another query in the same question from same document. Can you see the edited question above?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, can you have a look at my edited question please.

Comment: Your second quote is all about what I have already explained in my answer, just in different, more formal mode of expression.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: whenever `compareTo(a,b)` returns `0` for two objects `a` and `b`, `a.equals(b)` and `b.equals(a)` should be `true`, and vice versa.

Long answer: as stated in the `Comparable` documentation, implementations of `Comparable` enforce a total ordering. One of the [properties of total ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_ordering) is "antisymmetry": if we define a total ordering ≤, then:

> If a ≤ b and b ≤ a then a = b

This is represented as the `0` return value of `compareTo()`.

This trait is exploited by the methods and classes mentioned in the text you quoted for more correct and efficient behavior.

Comment: I was editing the question to put another point which is creating confusion.

Comment: i completely understand the concept described by you guys. Thank you very much. Can you see my edited question and tell me why the second addition into sortedset.

Comment: @benz : like Marko, I'm not sure what's unclear here. You do notice that it's `!a.equals(b)`, and not `a.equals(b)`? If so, please edit your question further to specify what you don't understand about the statement.

Comment: i am dissecting the statement. The condition means that if a and b are not equal objects and their compare operation returns 0, add to the set. What i am confused is, why the second add operation won't let them add and size won't increase. This statement is confusing me.

Comment: @benz : because a Java `Set` work like a mathematical set - it contains **distinct** objects. So, if you've already added an object `a` and you later try to add and object `b` which is considered "the same" (by `equals()` at the least), the operation won't do anything, since, as far as the set is concerned, `b` is already **in the set**, since **it's "the same" as `a`**.

Answer (score 2):

You can see it in Set's documentation:

> Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an
>   explicit comparator is provided) must be *consistent with equals*
>   if it is to correctly implement the {@code Set} interface.  (See
>   {@code Comparable} or {@code Comparator} for a precise definition of
>   *consistent with equals*.)  **This is so because the {@code Set}
>   interface is defined in terms of the {@code equals} operation, but a
>   {@code TreeSet} instance performs all element comparisons using its
>   {@code compareTo} (or {@code compare}) method, so two elements that
>   are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the set,
>   equal**.  The behavior of a set *is* well-defined even if its
>   ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the
>   general contract of the {@code Set} interface.

Comment: I wonder how much it would have cost to have `TreeSet` support an "unordered items" node type, say that adding an item to a tree which already contains an item for which `compareTo` yields zero but `equals` returns `false` would create an "unordered items" node with the old and new items, and that a search which encounters an "unordered items" node would search both branches.  That would allow such a type to behave just like a normal `Set`, even though it would only perform *efficiently* if most items were distinguishable by rank.